# Biblatex: Format of \textcite and \cite not in accordance with Harvard style. Why?

Tags: biblatex, authoryear

I organize my references with Citavi and export my *.bib from there.
In my preamble and document, I use something similar like the following:

```
\documentclass[
draft=false,
paper=a5,
twoside=on,
DIV=calc,
fontsize=10pt,
BCOR=15.0mm,
parskip=half,
cleardoublepage=empty,
headsepline,
pagesize=luatex,
]
{scrbook}

%\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} %% Not required anymore acc. Ulrike Fischer (see commends).
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %% Not required anymore acc. Ulrike Fischer (see commends).
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage[strict=true,autostyle=true,german=quotes,english=british,debug=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,doi=true,style=bath,sorting=ynt]{biblatex} % 'style=bath' is simillar to 'style=authoryear', but has a better format for the reference list. Behaviour intext is both the same.
\addbibresource{refrences.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\begin{document}
    Das Eine wurde von \textcite{Danck.1958} geschrieben und \textcite{Zwiet.1959} schreibt den Rest dazu.
    Viele Interesante Dinge lassen sich aber auch in woanders finden~\cite[S.~4--12]{Nauma.1983}.
    Wie \textcite[S.~127]{Sandb.1981b} haben viele wichtige Persönlichkeiten eine Vielzahl von Titeln.

    \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
    \printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

And the corresponding entries in my `refrences.bib` are:

```
@article{Sandb.1981b,
 author = {Prof. Ph.D (Eng) Sandberg, Mats},
 year = {1981},
 title = {What is ventilation efficiency?},
 url = {https://ac.els-cdn.com/0360132381900287/1-s2.0-0360132381900287-main.pdf?_tid=3499f23e-0c15-47db-bc09-2dfc72d3ef2a&acdnat=1522140378_fa4daeeccd32931dd4c60ad957e115ec},
 keywords = {Luftaustauschwirkungsgrad;Luftwechselrate;L{\"u}ftung},
 urldate = {2018-03-27},
 pages = {123--135},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {16},
 issn = {03601323},
 journaltitle = {Building and Environment},
 shorthand = {Sandberg 1981},
 doi = {10.1016/0360-1323(81)90028-7},
 number = {2},
 abstract = {Some content},
 pagetotal = {13},
 file = {Sandberg 1981 - What is ventilation efficiency (3):D\:\\Users\\...\\Citavi 6\\Projects\\...\\Citavi Attachments\\Sandberg 1981 - What is ventilation efficiency (3).pdf:pdf}
}

@book{Nauma.1983,
 author = {Nauman, E. B. and Buffham, B. A.},
 year = {1983},
 title = {Mixing in continuous flow systems},
 publisher = {Wiley},
 isbn = {978-0471861911},
 shorthand = {Nauman et al. 1983},
 language = {eng},
 location = {New York},
 abstract = {},
 pagetotal = {XXVI, 271 S}
}

@article{Zwiet.1959,
 author = {Zwietering, Th.N.},
 year = {1959},
 title = {The degree of mixing in continuous flow systems},
 urldate = {2021-05-21},
 pages = {1--15},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {11},
 issn = {00092509},
 journaltitle = {Chemical Engineering Science},
 shorthand = {Zwietering 1959},
 doi = {10.1016/0009-2509(59)80068-3},
 number = {1},
 abstract = {},
 pagetotal = {15},
 file = {Zwietering 1959 - The degree of mixing (3):D\:\\Users\\...\\Citavi 6\\Projects\\...\\Citavi Attachments\\Zwietering 1959 - The degree of mixing (3).pdf:pdf}
}

@article{Danck.1958,
 author = {Danckwerts, P. V.},
 year = {1958},
 title = {The effect of incomplete mixing on homogeneous reactions},
 urldate = {2021-06-28},
 pages = {93--102},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {8},
 issn = {00092509},
 journaltitle = {Chemical Engineering Science},
 shorthand = {Danckwerts 1958},
 doi = {10.1016/0009-2509(58)80040-8},
 number = {1-2},
 abstract = {},
 pagetotal = {10},
 file = {Danckwerts 1958 - The effect of incomplete mixing:D\:\\Users\\...\\Lit\\Citavi 6\\Projects\\...\\Citavi Attachments\\Danckwerts 1958 - The effect of incomplete mixing.pdf:pdf},
}
```

From what is stated in the `biblatex` package I would expect and also like to have it like this:

> Das Eine wurde von Danckwerts (1958) geschrieben und Zwietering (1959) schreibt den Rest dazu. Viele Interesante
> Dinge lassen sich aber auch in woanders finden (Nauman et al. 1983, S.
> 4–12). Wie Sandberg (1981, S. 127) haben viele wichtige
> Persönlichkeiten eine Vielzahl von Titeln.

Unfortunately, my result looks similar to this:

> Das Eine wurde von Danckwerts (Danckwerts 1958)geschrieben und
> Zwietering (Zwietering 1959)
> schreibt den Rest dazu. Viele Interesante Dinge lassen sich aber auch
> in woanders finden Nauman et al. 1983, S. 4–12. Wie Prof. Ph.D (Eng)
> Sandberg (Sandberg 1981, S. 127) haben viele wichtige Persönlichkeiten
> eine Vielzahl von Titeln.

I don't get what I am doing wrong. Please, help me find out.

Comment: You are manually forcing the citation label with the `shorthand` field (e.g. `shorthand = {Sandberg 1981},`), which leads to the output you are getting. Using `shorthand` like this goes against the spirit of author-year styles. Remove the `shorthand` fields in your entries.

Comment: Note also that (academic) degrees and titles are traditionally *not* included in the bibliography (or citations). Indeed the name will not be parsed as expected (or in any useful way) if you include titles as in `author = {Prof. Ph.D (Eng) Sandberg, Mats},`. Make that read `author = {Sandberg, Mats},`.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you don't need to include the `S.` in the postnote argument. `biblatex` automatically adds the appropriate page prefix in the current language. You don't even need to explicitly type an en-dash with `--`: With a current version, `biblatex` automatically turns `-` into the appropriate dash. So `\cite[S.~4--12]{Nauma.1983}` could just be `\cite[4-12]{Nauma.1983}`.

Comment: Why do you use `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex? That shouldn't be needed  since 10 years at least.

Comment: @moewe: Thank you, your commends where quite helpful. Now, it looks nice and need.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you for your commend as well. I just used what I found in templates and other commends. Is there a good best practice guide for Luatex, which packages should be included and which not? I have the feeling my document is a bit faster now with commending these two packages out. Could that be?

Comment: Those two packages relate to pre-Unicode processing etc, from very long ago. Best practice is: if you are using a package or option or setting, there must be a reason. If the answer is, "I don't know; I just copied something." - well, that is a choice (perhaps there was only 5 minutes available, or perhaps ignorance that another package or setting has superseded the old one), but the choice is: What do you want the best practice standard to be? Congruent to: What is the best result of a Google-search? Certainly, the first one is not guaranteed to be best (nor the **n**th one, where **n** >∞).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the unexpected output, because the `.bib` entries force a particular citation output manually with `shorthand`.

In most author-year styles entries with a shorthand come out as "`<shorthand>`" if they are cited with `\cite{<key>}`, while `\textcite{<key>}` produces "`<authors>` (`<shorthand>`)".

This makes sense if you use `shorthand` as shown [in `biblatex-examples.bib`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib#L1185-L1206), where we have (abridged)

```
@inbook{kant:kpv,
  title        = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},
  date         = 1968,
  author       = {Kant, Immanuel},
  booktitle    = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft. Kritik der Urtheilskraft},
  bookauthor   = {Kant, Immanuel},
  maintitle    = {Kants Werke. Akademie Textausgabe},
  volume       = 5,
  publisher    = {Walter de Gruyter},
  location     = {Berlin},
  pages        = {1-163},
  shorthand    = {KpV},
}
```

So that `\parencite{kant:kpv}` gives "(KpV)", and `\textcite{kant:kpv}` gives "Kant (KpV)".

In the example entries there is no need for shorthands to obtain the output you want. The whole point of `biblatex` is that it can generate the (author-year) citation labels automatically. Indeed using the `shorthand` is actively harmful because it disables some of `biblatex` features. Furthermore, the `shorthand` requires unnecessary duplication of data.

**Drop all shorthands of the form `shorthand = {Zwietering 1959},` from your `.bib` file.**

---

Related to that issue (because using `shorthand` might have been a workaround to achieve the desired result here) note that (academic) degrees and titles are traditionally not included in the bibliography (or citations). Indeed the name will not be parsed as expected (or in any useful way) if you include titles as in `author = {Prof. Ph.D (Eng) Sandberg, Mats},`. Make that read just

```
author = {Sandberg, Mats},
```

it is no sign of disrespect to omit titles and degrees in the bibliography and I have never seen bibliographies in academic works include them.

---

Finally and not related to your issue, but you don't need to include the S. in the `postnote` argument. `biblatex` automatically adds the appropriate page prefix in the current language. You don't even need to explicitly type an en-dash with `--`: With a current version, `biblatex` automatically turns `-` into the appropriate dash. So `\cite[S.~4--12]{Nauma.1983}` could just be

```
\cite[4-12]{Nauma.1983}
```

---

Putting all this together I would change your code (if compiled with LuaLaTeX) to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[strict=true,autostyle=true,german=quotes,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=bath,sorting=ynt,doi=true,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Sandb.1981b,
  author       = {Sandberg, Mats},
  year         = {1981},
  title        = {What Is Ventilation Efficiency?},
  urldate      = {2018-03-27},
  pages        = {123-135},
  volume       = {16},
  issn         = {03601323},
  journaltitle = {Building and Environment},
  doi          = {10.1016/0360-1323(81)90028-7},
  number       = {2},
  pagetotal    = {13},
}
@book{Nauma.1983,
  author    = {Nauman, E. B. and Buffham, B. A.},
  year      = {1983},
  title     = {Mixing in Continuous Flow Systems},
  publisher = {Wiley},
  isbn      = {978-0471861911},
  location  = {New York},
  pagetotal = {XXVI, 271 S}
}
@article{Zwiet.1959,
  author       = {Zwietering, Th. N.},
  year         = {1959},
  title        = {The Degree of Mixing in Continuous Flow Systems},
  urldate      = {2021-05-21},
  pages        = {1-15},
  volume       = {11},
  issn         = {00092509},
  journaltitle = {Chemical Engineering Science},
  doi          = {10.1016/0009-2509(59)80068-3},
  number       = {1},
  pagetotal    = {15},
}
@article{Danck.1958,
  author       = {Danckwerts, P. V.},
  year         = {1958},
  title        = {The Effect of Incomplete Mixing
                  on Homogeneous Reactions},
  urldate      = {2021-06-28},
  pages        = {93-102},
  volume       = {8},
  issn         = {00092509},
  journaltitle = {Chemical Engineering Science},
  doi          = {10.1016/0009-2509(58)80040-8},
  number       = {1-2},
  pagetotal    = {10},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Das Eine wurde von \textcite{Danck.1958} geschrieben
  und \textcite{Zwiet.1959} schreibt den Rest dazu.
  Viele interessante Dinge lassen sich aber auch
  woanders finden~\cite[4--12]{Nauma.1983}.
  Wie \textcite[127]{Sandb.1981b} haben viele wichtige
  Persönlichkeiten eine Vielzahl von Titeln.

  \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
  \printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

and would get

[image: Das Eine wurde von Danckwerts (1958) geschrieben und Zwietering (1959) schreibt den Rest dazu. Viele interessante Dinge lassen sich aber auch woanders finden Nauman und Buffham, 1983, S.4–12. Wie Sandberg (1981, S.127) haben viele wichtige Persönlichkeiten eine Vielzahl von Titeln.]

I switched the orders of the languages passed to `babel` because everything looked like you want the main document language to be German. (The *last* language passed to `babel` is the main document language.)